# Using ajax and updating the database on the same url?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form which has a select tag that contains the numbers from 1-31. What I'm trying to do is update the database with the value in the select tag if the user changes it (the default value is the value in the database i.e `$drop_d`) **WITHOUT** reloading the page at all. 
The following code doesn't seem to work, I think there is a problem in the way I am sending my data to ajax.

This variable contains the default value:

```
  $drop_d =  $e_r[drop_d];
```

The form:

```
<form> Number of days:  <select name="dropD" id="dropID"> <?php for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++){  ?> <option value="<?php echo $i;?>" <?php if($i==$drop_d){ ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> > <?php echo $i;  } ?> </select> </form> <br />
```

Ajax:

```
<script>
$('#dropID').change(function(){
   alert(1);
    var url = document.URL;
    var blah = $('#dropID').val()
    alert(blah);
    alert(url);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {newFieldValue: blah},
        dataType: 'html'
    }).done( function(){
            alert(1);
            blah.hide();
        });
});
</script>
```

Update on database:

```
<?php
        $newFieldValue = $_POST['newFieldValue'];
        $updateD = 'UPDATE en SET drop_d = $newFieldValue WHERE name=$name;
        mysql_query($updateD);

             ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select#dropID').on('change' , function(){
    var url = document.URL;
    var blah =  $('select#dropID').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {newFieldValue:blah},
        dataType: 'html'
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried this change but it doesn't do anything. I added a `.done` after the ajax and added an alert to that. That alert doesn't run, so there is something wrong with the ajax.

Comment: I updated my ajax , I get this error in my console `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'done' `

Answer (score 0):

You have defined an id value `id="dropID`, so your jQuery should be:

```
$('#dropID').val()
```

Comment: Sure. You can directly access the id, because it should be unique.

Comment: @user2441391 It *should* be `$("#dropID").val()`, as `dropD` is the name, not the ID.  I think he'll be fixing his answer :p

Comment: yes, that's what I thought. I changed that but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you look into the Console if there are any errors, or check the Network Tab if the Request is getting sent?

Comment: better would be to test step by step like first trying to alert the `$('select#dropID').val()` on change and so on

Comment: The change event hasn't been changed in this answer.  @wordpresser your answer is much clearer.

Comment: yes the `$('select#dropID').val()` on change alert works. It's probably the ajax. I will check the console.